# c++ problem with vector push_back

Tags: c++, class, stl, dictionary

UPDATE:
The following code gives me an error

> Graph.cpp: In function 'std::ostream&
>   operator<<(std::ostream&, const
>   Graph&)': Graph.cpp:43: error: passing
>   'const std::map >,
>   std::less,
>   std::allocator > > > >' as
>   'this' argument of '_Tp&
>   std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare,
>   _Alloc>::operator[](const _Key&) [with _Key = long int, _Tp = std::vector >, _Compare =
>   std::less, _Alloc =
>   std::allocator > > >]'
>   discards qualifiers Graph.cpp:44:
>   error: passing 'const std::map >,
>   std::less,
>   std::allocator > > > >' as
>   'this' argument of '_Tp&
>   std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare,
>   _Alloc>::operator[](const _Key&) [with _Key = long int, _Tp = std::vector >, _Compare =
>   std::less, _Alloc =
>   std::allocator > > >]'
>   discards qualifiers make[2]: ***
>   [build/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/Graph.o] Error
>   1

```
class Graph {
public:
    Graph();
    Graph(const Graph& orig);
    virtual ~Graph();

    void clear();
    void rgg(lint, double);
    bool is_directed() { return directed; }
    friend ostream& operator<< (ostream&, const Graph&); 


private:
    map< lint, vector<lint> > adjList;
    vector< pair<double, double> > xy;
    double radius;
    MTRand Rand;
    bool directed;
};


void Graph::rgg(lint n, double r) {
    radius = r; directed = false;

    clear(); 

    for(lint i = 0; i < n; i++)
        xy.push_back(pair<double, double>(Rand.rand(), Rand.rand()));
}

ostream& operator<< (ostream& os, const Graph& inGraph) {
    for(lint i = 0; i < inGraph.nodes; i++) {
        os << i << " ";
        if( inGraph.adjList.find(i) != inGraph.adjList.end() ) {
            for(lint idx = 0; idx < (inGraph.adjList[i]).size(); idx++ )
                os << inGraph.adjList[i].at(idx) << " ";

        }
        os << endl;
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance,

Comment: You have a destructor and copy-constructor, but I don't see a copy assignment operator. [Why?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29)

Comment: Why have you completely changed the question? Now none of the answers already posted make sense which will completely confuse anyone reading the question in the future. Please revert your change and post a new question if you want further help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause of your problems is that map's `operator[]` is a mutable operation (if the key doesn't exist, it will be added to the map).

You will have to use the iterator returned from `find()`:

```
map< lint, vector<lint> >::const_iterator it = inGraph.adjList.find(i);
if (it != inGraph.adjList.end();
for(lint idx = 0; idx < it->size(); idx++ )
    os << it->at(idx) << " ";
```

Answer (score 4):

I suspect that you mean Rand instead of MTRand:

```
Rand.rand()
```

MTRand is the name of the type. Rand is the name of the instance you created.

Answer (score 4):

Just a guess, but did you try

```
 xy.push_back(pair<double, double>(MTRand.rand(), MTRand.rand())
```

according to the declation of xy?

EDIT: seems the OP has changed it's code, now my answer does not match the new question any more. Nevertheless, hope my answer was useful.